# Change Network location from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, network, proxy

I have a two locations set up on my macBook. One for normal use and another for when I use a proxy, which I start from the command line.  It would be very useful for me to be able to switch network location from the command line at the same time.  Is this possible?

Comment: I was about to ask this question, when I see it was already asked. This is my exact same situation. My name is also Joe. Are you future-me come back to help now-me?

Comment: @JShoe I can't tell you that. But you should definately avoid anyone with a tatoo of a goldfish.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yep, pretty easy too.  You may need to 'sudo' the command depending on your system's configuration.

```
networksetup -switchtolocation "location name"
```

There are some other options, too:

```
networksetup -getcurrentlocation
networksetup -listlocations
networksetup -createlocation <location name> [populate]
networksetup -deletelocation <location name>
networksetup -switchtolocation <location name>
```

Comment: Is there a way to set this via a config file?

Comment: this could help with the automated configuration. https://github.com/rimar/wifi-location-changer